# How does a migration use duplicate titles, but a regular question not?

Tags: discussion, migration, title, cross-posting

This question was asked on Stack Overflow:

- [What is the correct format for final block in EVP_DecryptFinal_ex for decryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27763420/608639)
- Question number 27763420 (from the 'Share' link)

And then this question was migrated from Info Security SE (same author, same question):

- [What is the correct format for final block in EVP_DecryptFinal_ex for decryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27768555/608639)
- Question number 27768555 (from the 'Share' link)

How does a migration manage to duplicate a title?

Why is a regular question not allowed to duplicate a title?

Comment: There'd be little point in failing a migration for that reason. We can always close exact duplicates later on, but the initial goal (preventing people posting the same question over and over again) has *already* failed (the second question was already been posted). Now that it exists, we may as well handle it.

Comment: system could at least raise an automatic flag to let moderator close the blatant dupe, without waiting for someone to find out and push it into close queue (where there's always a risk of close vote expiry)

Comment: I'm suspecting that you want to ask a support question, since users most likely won't know the internals.

Comment: I'm wondering why did you provided the question number? Because they are already there in the links you provided. Just curious. And about the question I think migration must use the same name as Martijin said because in other way it would make even more complicate moderator's live.

Comment: @MartijnPieters FWIW, [Tim Post mentioned here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/what-difficulties-could-be-there-in-establishing-automatic-checks-for-so-cross-p?lq=1#comment17969_6660): _"There is a check to see if a duplicate exists on a destination site which rejects a migration if so..."_ (I guess in this particular case check failed to trigger migration rejection because of some tiny difference)

Comment: @gnat: interesting! The titles appear to be **exactly** the same (programmatically testing if the titles are the same show they match) so unless there is some hidden whitespace issue I failed to detect these should have been handled as dupes by that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters are tags the same? (I don't have 10K to check [this one, deleted by author](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768555/what-is-the-correct-format-for-final-block-in-evp-decryptfinal-ex-for-decryption))

Comment: @gnat: no, the tags differ; the deleted post used [tag:cryptography], [tag:openssl], and [tag:aes]. However, when migrating you cannot assume the same tags exist.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it would be _really_ weird if it turns out that tags difference was the only reason for dupe-check to fail. Anyway, if SE team is that reluctant about fully automatic migration rejection, they could at least raise automatic flag as I mentioned above if either of title / body of the question are identical