# How was a user able to post a question with a title identical to an existing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, title

The following question was asked 5 days ago:
*[Object Reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094648/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)*

**How was the author able to post the question when [there are already 58 old other questions with the same exact title](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/653093)?**

I've checked that:

- [The post was not migrated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281734/how-does-a-migration-use-duplicate-titles-but-a-regular-question-not)
- [The post was not deleted then undeleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343016/bypassing-the-duplicate-title-filter-by-deleting-then-undeleting)
- [Its title does not contain invisible characters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346036/questions-with-invisible-characters-to-workaround-title-length-minimum)

What I did not check, because unlikely:

- The author is probably not an employee of Stack Overflow, Inc

(In case you're skeptical about those 58 identical titles, here are some random picks: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201989/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341999/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245315/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056156/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862977/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object), ...)

Comment: Should these questions with identical titles be marked as duplicates?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It depends. Often not. It's about the content, and in priority these questions should have their titles disambiguated. If disambiguation isn't possible, then yes, they are duplicate.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The author posted it with a space at the end. This got it past the check, since none of the existing titles ends with a space. At that point, the system stripped the space before posting it thus ensuring that the next person to try this will *also* be able to get past the check by tacking on a space.

I'm marking this as a bug, because we should probably be normalizing the titles *before* running the dup-check.

#### Related: [Forbidden word (help) got into question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292376/forbidden-word-help-got-into-question-title)

Comment: Does this cover the entire 58/59? I thought that some of the much earlier posts in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/653104) would be pre-title check (introduced 2011/12 ish?) and was puzzled about the rest - except it was looking like a distinct title and tag set would be about right for the results....

Comment: "we should probably be normalizing the titles" Did you mean: ***definitely***

Comment: I don't remember when the title check was implemented, @Jon, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't some equivalent of a call to Trim() on titles from the very start... Regardless, I cannot find a single example in the database of a question with a title that has trailing spaces. The problem - as I said above - is that we perform this cleanup *after* running the dup-check.

Comment: When I posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346334/time-to-take-a-dance) my first title was "time to take a stand". That errored out so I tried "time to take a stand ", notice the space. That errored out too so it seems like the space check is already implemented, not sure how the question got through it though.

Comment: I just did a test https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208414/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object adding a space at the end definately works. Of course self deleted it too again.

Comment: universe is making better idiots every second

Comment: @dorukayhan, when the question states `author is probably not an employee` then the answer should probably use the same (very British) understated tone!

Comment: Makes me think of Ender's Game

Comment: Reminds me of this one from long ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158666/how-did-this-question-bypass-the-dupe-title-filter-and-the-question-rate-limit

Comment: @Shog9 "_I cannot find a single example in the database of a question with a title that has trailing spaces._". Was your query correct? Because I just found one from 2011 (edited now): https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4591259/revisions

Comment: Yep, bug in my query @Cœur - I forgot that SQL Server ignores trailing spaces when comparing strings. Looks like [we didn't strip these until late 2012!](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/714627)

Comment: So that's about 6500 titles with trailing spaces.

Answer (score 6):

So, I finally closed the loophole here...

I've ensured the space normalisation we do on titles before inserting to the DB also happens before we compare a title to existing ones. This catches these cases.

This has been deployed now.

Comment: Oh... I predict an increase of spelling mistakes now...

Comment: **Intentional** spelling mistakes