# Posted a question with already existed title after immediate edit

Tags: bug, edits, grace-period

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691846/fastlane-command-not-found). At first I couldn't add a question with the system check with the title:

*"fastlane command not found"* because a question with similar title already exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369197/fastlane-command-not-found). So I added the question with title *"fastlane command not found - Xcode Bot"*

Just to test if I can make my title similar with the existed question title, I made an immediate edit which doesn't appear in **edit history**, and it eventually got approved.

I think the system should also check the title if it already exists with the similar title while editing too.

Comment: I'm wondering if recent posts in [this list of questions with the same title](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/664836) achieved the duplicate title by leveraging this bug.

Comment: Maybe related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346414/how-was-a-user-able-to-post-a-question-with-a-title-identical-to-an-existing

Comment: @Jarrod Irrelevant to the issue at hand though.