# How come these two questions have the same title?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title

These questions were asked by the same user: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64219589/509868) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64220414/509868). They have identical titles. I remember that the system has a check for exactly this. How did it fail in this case?

Something like this happened before ([link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346414/509868)); in that case the user added a space to the title, but I think this case is different - no additional space as far as I can see.

Comment: Does the check consider deleted posts? The first question had been deleted 30 minutes before the second one was posted.

Comment: Oh yes, that must be it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The title restriction only checks for posts that are not deleted *at the time of posting*.

The first post was deleted (by the OP) shortly before they posted the second question (at 05:45 UTC and 06:27 UTC, respectively), so at that time the title was not restricted.

The first post was later undeleted (over two weeks later, via undelete votes cast by 3 community members).